# Expo Audio staysActiveInBackground is not working

Tags: react-native, audio, expo

I am trying to listen to music (streaming) in background but the streaming stop when I open another app.

```
  const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();

  async function playAudio() {
    try {
      await soundObject.loadAsync({
        uri: "http://suaradio2.dyndns.ws:11004/stream"
      });
      await soundObject.playAsync();
      soundObject.setAudioModeAsync({
        staysActiveInBackground: true
      });
      // Your sound is playing!
    } catch (error) {
      // An error occurred!
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you try on Android or IOS?

Comment: with standalone or expo client

Comment: @Oleg Yes, I did... I tried on Android with Expo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created working snack: https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/staysactiveinbackground

You have to set all params of setAudioModeAsync:

```
await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        staysActiveInBackground: true,
        interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
        shouldDuckAndroid: true,
        playThroughEarpieceAndroid: true,
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work on Android but will not work on iOS with expo. Need to add the following code in the app.json

```
"ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0",
      "infoPlist": {
        "UIBackgroundModes": [
          "audio"
        ]
      }
    },
```

After that, You have to create standalone application of iOS and it will work on standalone application.